# Python API gets invalid json

Tags: python, json

I have just started using python a few days ago and get work out the JSON format.

I use requests to get JSON data by API. However, I get the wrong decoded JSON format (JSON validator finds errors).

```
webpage = 'https://parser-api.com/parser/arbitr_api/run.php'
API = 'cant post it' # 

output_results = []

cases = ['А65-22925/2017']

for i in cases:

    params = {'key':API, 'CaseNumber':i}
    results = requests.get(webpage, params = params)
    output_results.append(results.text)

print (output_results)

with open ('file_name_case.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as wr:
    wr.write (str(output_results))
```

that is the snippet of the response that I get, which is wrong:

```
['{"Cases":[{"CaseId":"998ecaef-3da8-45ab-9f56-90bfc3375e11","CaseNumber":"\\u041065-22925\\/2017","CaseType":"\\u0410","Thirds":[],"Plaintiffs":[{"Name":"\\u041e\\u041e\\u041e \\"\\u0412\\u0420-\\u041f\\u043b\\u0430\\u0441\\u0442\\", \\u0433.\\u041a\\u0430\\u0437\\u0430\\u043d\\u044c","Address":"421001, \\u0420\\u043e\\u0441\\u0441\\u0438\\u044f, \\u0433.\\u041a\\u0430\\u0437\\u0430\\u043d\\u044c, \\u0420\\u0422, \\u0443\\u043b.\\u0421.\\u0425\\u0430\\u043a\\u0438\\u043c\\u0430, \\u0434.60, \\u043e\\u0444\\u0438\\u0441 164","Id":"dc26df83-6361-4de0-bc93-8c20ae0a4417"}],"Respondents":[{"Name":"\\u0424\\u0435\\u0434\\u0435\\u0440\\u0430\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0430\\u044f \\u0422\\u0430\\u043c\\u043e\\u0436\\u0435\\u043d\\u043d\\u0430\\u044f \\u0441\\u043b\\u0443\\u0436\\u0431\\u0430 \\u041f\\u0440\\u0438\\u0432\\u043e\\u043b\\u0436\\u0441\\u043a\\u043e\\u0435 \\u0442\\u0430\\u043c\\u043e\\u0436\\u0435\\u043d\\u043d\\u043e\\u0435 \\u0443\\u043f\\u0440\\u0430\\u0432\\u043b\\u0435\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435 \\u0422\\u0430\\u0442\\u0430\\u0440\\u0441\\u0442\\u0430\\u043d\\u0441\\u043a\\u0430\\u044f \\u0442\\u0430\\u043c\\u043e\\u0436\\u043d\\u044f, \\u0433.\\u041a\\u0430\\u0437\\u0430\\u043d\\u044c","Address":"420094, \\u0420\\u043e\\u0441\\u0441\\u0438\\u044f, \\u0433.\\u041a\\u0430\\u0437\\u0430\\u043d\\u044c, \\u0420\\u0422, \\u0443\\u043b.\\u041a\\u043e\\u0440\\u043e\\u043b\\u0435\\u043d\\u043a\\u043e, \\u0434.56","Id":"4b21e3e9-9d0c-42ce-bbec-4e1615e34698"}]...
```

the right format suppose to be like this:

```
{"Cases":[{"CaseId":"998ecaef-3da8-45ab-9f56-90bfc3375e11","CaseNumber":"\u041065-22925\/2017","CaseType":"\u0410","Thirds":[],"Plaintiffs":[{"Name":"\u041e\u041e\u041e \"\u0412\u0420-\u041f\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0442\", \u0433.\u041a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u043d\u044c","Address":"421001, \u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f, \u0433.\u041a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u043d\u044c, \u0420\u0422, \u0443\u043b.\u0421.\u0425\u0430\u043a\u0438\u043c\u0430, \u0434.60, \u043e\u0444\u0438\u0441 164","Id":"dc26df83-6361-4de0-bc93-8c20ae0a4417"}],"Respondents":[{"Name":"\u0424\u0435\u0434\u0435\u0440\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0422\u0430\u043c\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0441\u043b\u0443\u0436\u0431\u0430 \u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u043e\u043b\u0436\u0441\u043a\u043e\u0435 \u0442\u0430\u043c\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0443\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0422\u0430\u0442\u0430\u0440\u0441\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f \u0442\u0430\u043c\u043e\u0436\u043d\u044f, \u0433.\u041a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u043d\u044c","Address":"420094, \u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f, \u0433.\u041a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u043d\u044c, \u0420\u0422, \u0443\u043b.\u041a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e, \u0434.56","Id":"4b21e3e9-9d0c-42ce-bbec-4e1615e34698"}]
```

Please help

Comment: Try using *results.json* (instead of *results.text*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import json
with open('file_name_case.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been breaking my head because json.dump always gave me ('NoneType' object has no attribute 'load') error. Now its working, though I don't understand why :)

Answer (score 0):

Although Python syntax is very similar in many ways to JSON syntax it is not valid JSON to just `str(<some python object>)`.  You need to use the `json` module to write JSON.

Instead of taking `results.text` directly, use `results.json()` to decode the JSON response from the server.

Now you have a Python `list` of `dict`s as opposed to a Python list of strings containing JSON.

Then, as in [kup's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68587286/982257) you can convert back to JSON:

```py
output_results = []

for idx in cases:
    params = {'key': API, 'CaseNumber': idx}
    results = requests.get(webpage, params=params)
    output_results.append(results.json())

with open('file_name_case.json', 'w') as fobj:
    json.dump(output_results, fobj)
```

Comment: Thank you, Iguananaut! It works as well! I dont know why, but json.dump gave me of ('NoneType' object has no attribute 'load') error before... maybe the change of filename worked, don't know.

Comment: You need to `import json` and don't use the variable `json` for something else.